# Android repeating alarm in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

My alarm starts notification service. A want my alarm fire every 7th day of every month at 14:00

**My receiver:**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("RECEIVER STARTED");
    if (checkForDay()) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent1, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
        System.out.println("ALARM SET");
    } else
        System.out.println("ALARM NOT SET");
}

private boolean checkForDay() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    return calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == 7;

}
```

My receiver starts at BOOT_COMPLETE and from broadcast in MainActivity onCreate();
But there are problems.

1. What if user keep the phone 24/7 booted
2. User can start my app after 14:00 and alarm fires instantly - dont want it. Only at 14:00
3. Uset can forget to start my app and alarm will not fire at all

**How to implement right Repeating Monthly alarm** if setInexactRepeating() is not good, because of interval. Its not the same every month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### case 1 : [What if user keep the phone 24/7 booted]

In this case, everything goes straight. When alarm fired on 7th day at 14:00 , you can set next alarm for next  7th day

### case 2 : [User can start my app after 14:00 and alarm fires instantly - dont want it. Only at 14:00]

In this case , just add one check to process or not to process your logic you need to execute on 7th day of every month at 14:00

### Case 3 : [User can forget to start my app and alarm will not fire at all]

You can use Reboot event ,it works.